# Creating an array of successive matrix powers in python: what is optimal?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch, linear-algebra

I often have to create an array of matrices containing successive powers of an operator
(e.g. when integrating an ordinary differential equation, or computing a polynomial function of an operator).

However I can't figure what is the best way to do this. It seems like using a for-loop is rather wise, so that one may incrementally fill in the array by multiplying `x**(k-1)` with `x` to get `x**k`, and avoid repeating too many costly matrix multiplications. Is there any better construct to be aware of?

For instance, say I have represented a rank-k polynomial `p` as a 1D-array of shape (k),
and  want to write a function `evaluate` that applies a polynomial to a square matrix `x` of shape (n, n):

```py
def evaluate1 (p, x):
    return np.sum(p * (x ** np.arange(p.shape[0])))

def evaluate2 (p, x):
    powers = [1]
    for i in range(1, p.shape[0]):
        powers.append(np.matmul(powers[-1], x))
    return np.sum(p * np.array(powers))
```

I would naively say that `evaluate1` outperforms `evaluate2` by making use of vectorisation for small `n`...

Is there any `evaluate3` to follow best practices?

Comment: For polynomials you might want to consider horner's rule, for example a0+a1*X+a2*X*X+a3*X*X*X can be evaluated as a0*I+X*(a1*I+X*(a2*I+X*a3))

Comment: Would it be efficient if implemented with a recursive evaluation function?

Comment: Sometimes you just have to time test the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

A more optimal way would be to make use of exponential powers.

To give an example, lets say `p=8`:
We could then simply calculate the answer in only 3 steps instead of 8 (evaluate2):

```
1. x2 = x*x
2. x4 = x2*x2
3. x8 = x4*x4 (our desired answer)
```

This way the time-complexity reduces to `log(p)` instead of linear in `p`

I think the code for it is straightforward.

Comment: This is very interesting, yet I usually do need all powers in the range

Comment: Not really, you can achieve your answer by only maintaining a memoized list of `|log(p)|` exponential-matrix-multiplications. For example: `x^11 = x^8 * x^2 * x`

Comment: Yes, but how would you compute `x^3 + 3 x^7 - 4 x^8 + 2 x^11` then ?

Comment: @SerialLazer |log(p)| does it for any single item. But OP needs `n` single items.

Answer (score 0):

The first evaluate is a good point to start with except that

`out = x ** np.arange(p.shape[0])`

is not optimal.

You could use a benefit of [`np.cumprod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html) and replace it with:

```
y = np.full(p.shape[0], x)
y[0] = 1
out = np.cumprod(y)
```

#### Update

An exception into a calculation of multiple polynomial values:

```
p = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,-4,0,0,0,2]
args = [1,2,3,5,10]
val_matrix = np.repeat(args, len(p)).reshape(-1, len(p))
val_matrix[:, 0] = 1
val_matrix = np.cumprod(val_matrix, axis=1)
vals = np.sum(p * val_matrix, axis = 1)
```

Sample run for `P(x) = x^3 + 3x^7 - 4x^8 + 2x^11` and `args = [1,2,3,5,10]`:

```
>>> p = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,-4,0,0,0,2]
...
>>> for n in val_matrix.tolist(): print(n)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096]
[1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243, 729, 2187, 6561, 19683, 59049, 177147, 531441]
[1, 5, 25, 125, 625, 3125, 15625, 78125, 390625, 1953125, 9765625, 48828125, 244140625]
[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000, 1410065408, 1215752192, -727379968]
>>> vals
array([          2,        7560,     1043226,   486953250, -1824758936])
```

**Warning:** invalid values are encountered for arg = 10. You can add a temporary fix for this in this way:

```
#replace val_matrix = np.repeat(args, len(p)).reshape(-1, len(p)) with
val_matrix = np.repeat(args, len(p)).reshape(-1, len(p)).astype(np.int64)
```

Comment: Oh thanks.... so `np.cumprod` looks like what I was looking for :)

Comment: As mentioned in post, I am in fact rather looking for something that behaves like cumprod but for matrices.

Comment: @shevket Does adding `axis=1` parameter in `np.sum` method help for you?

Comment: No, the problem is you can't tell `np.cumprod` to treat last two dimensions as matrix dimensions and perform some kind of `np.cummatmul`... It just multiplies coefficient-wise